# API бэкенд для Android приложения

Tags: java, android, api, servlet, мобильная-разработка

Разрабатываю Android приложение, которое включает в себя работу с БД (регистрация пользователя и т.д.). В следствии чего необходимо разработать API которое будет обрабатывать запросы моего Android приложения. 
API и Android приложение пишу на java. Если правильно понял, для api на java необходимо будет использовать сервлеты.
Подскажите пожалуйста что стоит использовать/чего лучше не использовать в моём случаи (с примерами реализации если такие имеются).
Заранее большое спасибо.
**Бэкенд как и приложение только на java.**

Comment: поскольку вы решили использовать HTTP запросы, то тут не будет однозначного мнения, т.к. на бекэнде вы можете использовать любой язык и любую технологию.

Comment: Подправил пост (добавил: бэкенд как и приложение только на java). К сожалению кроме HTTP запросов, другой безопасный доступ к БД придумать не смог. Буду рад если предложите альтернативный способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть желание познакомиться с часто используемыми фреймворками, то берите `Spring` + `Hibernate`. Почитайте документацию + примеры и вперед.

Мне на старте очень помогли видео :

[Разработка MVC приложения на Java за два часа](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9dvZyEofAg)

[Java приложение с использованием Hibernate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tab1LOG25ww)

В нем вам покажут пошаговое построение каркаса для вашего приложения. Первый час там идет теория. Второй час практика.

Если я верно вас понял, то скорее всего вы будете использовать `REST`, т.е. `jsp` и представления вам будут ненужны, но уже будет небольшой фундамент для дальнейшего изучения и использования.

---

Второй вариант это использовать `servlet'ы` и `jdbc`, хороших материалов по этому не подскажу, т.к. тема большая и что-то одно выделить сложно. Но информации много как на хабре так и тут, молчу про англоязычные ресурсы.

---

А вообще вы можете состряпать любого монстра

- spring + jdbc
- spring + hibernate
- servlet + hibernate
- servlet + jdbc

`Spring` и `hibernate` просто популярные поэтому по ним много информации.  Servlet и jdbc старые технологии, поэтому по ним тоже накопился большой багаж знаний.

Answer (score 0):

Советую бесплатные курсы от `mail.ru` на платформе `stepik.org`

[Разработка веб сервиса на Java (часть 1)](https://stepik.org/course/146)

[Разработка веб сервиса на Java (часть 2)](https://stepik.org/course/186)

В курсе в качестве HTTP сервера используется `Jetty`, а так же используют Hibernate, если у вас есть время, то думаю вы не пожалеете, хотя `Spring` тоже не плохой вариант, но в вашем случае лучше использовать `Spring Boot`

Answer (score 0):

**Исключительно советую**:
(так как сам не первый раз стряпаю на этом сервера для всевозможных чатов, игр итд...)

https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio

Из основных плюсов:

- Простота внедрения, переезда
- Скорость работы, не требовательность.
- Поддержка SSL